CNN-LSTM for Predictive Analysis
UPDATED WITH CODE
The CNN network I've made for predictive analysis using the public NASA TurboFan DataSet 1 seems to overfit consistently.
I have tried more/less epochs, various batch sizes, and messed around with the model architecture/design. No matter how the training goes, the test set predictions always land around 50 - 100 MAE.
Training Set Dims: (100, 364, 14) -> (batch, cycles, features)
Testing Set Dims: (100, 364, 14) -> (batch, cycles, features)
For this dataset some engines die off faster than others. So all engine batches are truncated up to the max cycle of 364 - the excess rows filled with zeros.
I am pretty new to neural networks so please feel free to tear me apart mercilessly! How can I improve the network?
DATASETS available @ https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/behrad3d/nasa-cmaps/data
Train, Test, RUL Dataset: FD001
Training Data Prep
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

training_data = pd.read_csv('../data/train1.csv')
testing_data = pd.read_csv('../data/test1.csv')
rul = pd.read_csv('../data/RUL1.csv')

# Drop columns with constant values
training_data_nconst = pd.read_csv('~/raytheon/data/train1.csv')
print(f'Previous Training Shape : {training_data_nconst.shape}') 

for column in training_data_nconst.columns:
    if training_data_nconst[column].std() < 0.01:
        training_data_nconst.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)
    
# Drop the usual suspects
training_data_nconst.drop(['Unit', 'Cycle', 'RUL'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(f'New Training Shape : {training_data_nconst.shape}')
training_data_nconst.describe()

# from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
training_data_normalized = training_data.copy()
training_data_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(training_data_nconst)
print(training_data_normalized)

# Correcting column names based on the initial setup
feature_columns = column_names = ["T24", "T30", "T50", "P30", "Nf", "Nc", "Ps30", 
              "phi", "NRf", "NRc", "BPR", "htBleed", "W31", "W32"]
training_DataFrame_normalized = pd.DataFrame(training_data_normalized, columns=feature_columns)

# Add back the 'Unit #' and 'Time Cycle' columns from the original training data
training_DataFrame_normalized.insert(0, 'Cycle', training_data['Cycle'])
training_DataFrame_normalized.insert(0, 'Unit', training_data['Unit'])

training_DataFrame_normalized.insert(16, 'RUL', training_data['RUL'])

# Find the largest engine subset using max_cycle.
max_cycle_length = training_DataFrame_normalized['Cycle'].max()
print(f'Most cycles: {max_cycle_length}')

'''Break the training data into engine subsets.
Scale up other subsets. Just fill in 0's for new rows. (Thinking failure - 0 sensor output..?)'''
engine_data_subsets = {}

for unit in training_DataFrame_normalized['Unit'].unique():
    engine_subset = training_DataFrame_normalized.loc[training_DataFrame_normalized['Unit'] == unit]
    
    # Find the maximum cycle number for the current engine
    max_cycle_engine = engine_subset['Cycle'].max()

    # Calculate padding length for this engine
    padding_length = max_cycle_length - max_cycle_engine

    # Create a padding DataFrame with zeros for sensor columns (excluding 'Unit' and 'Cycle')
    if padding_length > 0:
        padding_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(padding_length), columns=engine_subset.columns[2:])
        padding_df['Unit'] = unit
        padding_df['Cycle'] = range(max_cycle_engine + 1, max_cycle_engine + 1 + padding_length)
        
        # Concatenate the padding DataFrame to the end of the engine_subset
        engine_subset = pd.concat([engine_subset, padding_df], ignore_index=True)
        
    engine_data_subsets[unit] = engine_subset
print(engine_data_subsets[100])


engine_1_data = engine_data_subsets[1]
sensor_columns = feature_columns

Testing Data Prep
# Drop columns with constant values
test_data_nconst = pd.read_csv('~/raytheon/data/test1.csv')
print(f'Previous Testing Shape : {test_data_nconst.shape}') 

for column in test_data_nconst.columns:
    if test_data_nconst[column].std() < 0.01:
        test_data_nconst.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)
        
# Drop the usual suspects
test_data_nconst.drop(['Unit', 'Cycle'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        
print(f'New Training Shape : {test_data_nconst.shape}')
test_data_nconst.describe()

# from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
test_data_normalized = testing_data.copy()
test_data_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(test_data_nconst)
print(test_data_normalized)

test_DataFrame_normalized = pd.DataFrame(test_data_normalized, columns=feature_columns)

# Add back the 'Unit #' and 'Time Cycle' columns from the original training data
test_DataFrame_normalized.insert(0, 'Cycle', testing_data['Cycle'])
test_DataFrame_normalized.insert(0, 'Unit', testing_data['Unit'])

# Find the largest engine subset using max_cycle.
max_test_cycle_length = test_DataFrame_normalized.groupby('Unit')['Cycle'].max().max()
print(f'Most cycles: {max_test_cycle_length}')

test_engine_data_subsets = {}

for unit in test_DataFrame_normalized['Unit'].unique():
    test_engine_subset = test_DataFrame_normalized.loc[test_DataFrame_normalized['Unit'] == unit]
    
    # Find the maximum cycle number for the current engine
    max_test_cycle_engine = test_engine_subset['Cycle'].max()

    # Calculate padding length for this engine
    padding_length = max_test_cycle_length - max_test_cycle_engine

    # Create a padding DataFrame with zeros for sensor columns (excluding 'Unit' and 'Cycle')
    if padding_length > 0:
        padding_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(padding_length), columns=test_engine_subset.columns[2:])
        padding_df['Unit'] = unit
        padding_df['Cycle'] = range(max_test_cycle_engine + 1, max_test_cycle_engine + 1 + padding_length)
        
        # Concatenate the padding DataFrame to the end of the engine_subset
        test_engine_subset = pd.concat([test_engine_subset, padding_df], ignore_index=True)
        
    test_engine_data_subsets[unit] = test_engine_subset
test_engine_data_subsets[100]

# Get the data for engine 1
test_engine_1_data = test_engine_data_subsets[1]
test_sensor_columns = feature_columns

Model Inputs and Define
import numpy as np

# Each value in engine_data_subsets is a numpy array of shape (cycle_count, num_features)
batch_num = len(engine_data_subsets)

# Assuming all arrays have the same shape, get the shape of the first array
example_array = next(iter(engine_data_subsets.values()))
cycle_count, num_features = example_array.shape

X_train = np.zeros((batch_num, cycle_count, num_features))

for i, array in enumerate(engine_data_subsets.values()):
    X_train[i, :, :] = array

y_train = training_DataFrame_normalized.groupby('Unit')['RUL'].max()

# Remove non-features from INPUT
X_train = X_train[:,:,2:16]
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (100, 1))
print('X Train set shape', X_train.shape)
print('y Train set shape', y_train.shape)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

# Define the model
model = Sequential()

# Convolutional layers
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=62, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

# Flattening layer
model.add(Flatten())

# Fully connected layers
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])

# Print model summary
model.summary()

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
predictions = model.predict(X_train)
predictions.shape

from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score
# Calculate Mean Absolute Error (MAE)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_train, predictions)
print("Mean Absolute Error (MAE):", mae)

# Calculate Mean Squared Error (MSE)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_train, predictions)
print("Mean Squared Error (MSE):", mse)

result_train = pd.DataFrame(y_train)
result_train['Predictions'] = predictions.round(0)
result_train

# Each value in engine_data_subsets is a numpy array of shape (cycle_count, num_features)
batch_num = len(test_engine_data_subsets)

# Assuming all arrays have the same shape, get the shape of the first array
example_array = next(iter(test_engine_data_subsets.values()))
cycle_count, num_features = example_array.shape

X_test = np.zeros((batch_num, cycle_count, num_features))

for i, array in enumerate(test_engine_data_subsets.values()):
    X_test[i, :, :] = array

y_test = rul['RUL']
#y_train = training_DataFrame_normalized.groupby('Unit')['RUL'].max()
print(f' INPUT Shape: {X_test.shape}')
print(f' OUTPUT Shape: {rul.shape}')

# Remove non-features from INPUT
X_test = X_test[:,:,2:16]
print(X_test.shape)

max_length = 362  # Maximum length of sequences
X_test_padded = np.zeros((X_test.shape[0], max_length, X_test.shape[2]))
for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
    X_test_padded[i, :X_test.shape[1], :] = X_test[i, :max_length, :]

print(X_test_padded.shape)
predictions_test = model.predict(X_test_padded)

# Calculate Mean Absolute Error (MAE)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, predictions_test)
print("Mean Absolute Error (MAE):", mae)

# Calculate Mean Squared Error (MSE)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions_test)
print("Mean Squared Error (MSE):", mse)

result_test = pd.DataFrame(y_test)
result_test['Predictions'] = predictions_test.round(0)
result_test




can you please copy and paste your code as text so that we can reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

@DerekO Done. I Included the link for the dataset as well.
